Comparison of trends in two time series

I have read through several posts regarding time series analysis, particularly in the situation of comparing 2+ time series, but am still unsure of the correct approach for my data. My dataset consists of repeated measures of a physiologic value each day for 30 days, for 50 subjects. On each day, there is an expected range for the value, consisting of the upper and lower bound. This is shown as the grey shaded area. The black trend line is the observed value each day. Each subject would have a unique set of expected ranges and observed values.
What I would like to do is compare the trend of the expected range to the trend of the observed values. In other words, does the trend of the observed values follow the trend of the expected range for this cohort, accounting for within subject variation.
My questions are:

What method would be most appropriate for analyzing this time series data?

Would it be best to compare the trend of the observed value to the trend of the daily mean of the upper and lower bounds, or treat the observed, upper bound, and lower bound as three separate time series?



You could compute the coverage of the expected interval: how often is the observed interval in the expected interval. Then compare to what you expect (what is the expected coverage of your interval)? If you want to compare different models for your expected intervals, then you should also measure how wide the expected intervals are. You aim for 1) tight intervals with 2) appropriate coverage (multi objective problem)

You might have to do this for each time series independently (or aggregate over these to get a scale measure, again see multi-objective optimization...)

Thank you @Ggjj11. I am not familiar with multi-objective optimization, so I will need to look into this. Are you aware of any good resources on this topic?

The carry over to your problem is a bit of a stretch, but remember: putting two goals into one number (scalarizarion) always comes with a trade-off and there are arbitrary many possible trade-offs

I would start with wikipedia: Pareto optimization

@calculating_cashews, it is not quite clear what you are trying to do. What is the point of 'analyzing the data'. Are you trying to find the time-series model that would fit your observations of the patients?

@Cryo, I am looking to determine if the time series of the observed values is significantly different from the time series series of the expected range

@calculating_cashews, expected range should already include in its definition what significant difference is. Is this expected range some sort of confidence interval? Then there must be a null hypothesis attached to it (what is it?), this will allow you to extract the null hypothesis for your trace.
